# 2nd messenger mechanisms

Tags: cell-biology, cell-signaling

Many hormones use [2nd messenger mechanisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_messenger_system), such as cAMP and cGMP, and also act on the same cells. For example calcitonin and PTH both use cAMP and have opposite effects.

How is it possible that the same second messenger molecule (cAMP) can have opposite effects on the same cells? Why are there more hormones compared to 2nd messengers - doesn't that reduce the uniqueness of each hormone? Shouldn't that make the function of any hormone using e.g. cAMP be the same as that of any other hormone using the same 2nd messenger on the same cell?

Comment: Yes. Got it! Thank you!